# Angular, hide parent when there are no child-elements with nested ng-repeat's

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know there are some posts on the subject, but I could get this specific example working,
because of the nesting:

I have a FAQ with 3 levels of nesting, rendered by ng-repeats,
I want to hide the Category and the Subcategory if the query returns no questions.

I made a Fiddle, can anyone help me get this to work?
http://jsfiddle.net/Lp02huqm/
Thanks!

HTML

```
<div ng-app="faqApp" ng-controller="FaqController">
    <input ng-model="query" type="text">
    <ul class="collapse-list">
        <li ng-repeat="category in faq | filter:matchEveryWord() | orderBy:rankOrder">       
            <h3>{{category.category}}</h3>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="subcategory in category.subcategories | filter:matchEveryWord()">       
                        <h3>{{subcategory.subcategory}}</h3>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li ng-repeat="question in subcategory.questions | filter:matchEveryWord()">       
                                    <h3>{{question.question}}</h3>
                                    <div>{{question.answer}}</div>       
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var faqApp = angular.module('faqApp', []);

faqApp.controller('FaqController', ['$scope' , function ($scope){


$scope.faq = [
    {category: 'Category1',
     rank:2,
     subcategories: [
         {subcategory: 'Subcategory1',
          questions: [
              {
                  question: 'this is the first question',
                  answer: 'this is the answer on the first question'
              },
              {
                  question: 'this is the second question',
                  answer: 'this is the answer on the second question'
              }

          ]
         },
         {subcategory: 'Subcategory2',
          questions: [
              {
                  question: 'this is the first question of the second subcategory',
                  answer: 'this is the answer on the first question of the second subcategory'
              },
              {
                  question: 'this is the second question',
                  answer: 'this is the answer on the second question'
              }

          ]
         }
     ]
    },
    {category: 'Category2',
     rank:1,
     subcategories: [
         {subcategory: 'Subcategory3',
          questions: [
              {
                  question: 'Apple',
                  answer: 'the answer to apple'
              },
              {
                  question: 'Banana',
                  answer: 'the answer to banana'
              }

          ]
         },
         {subcategory: 'Subcategory4',
          questions: [
              {
                  question: 'this is the first question of subcategory 4',
                  answer: 'this is the answer on the first question of subcategory 4'
              }
          ]
         }
     ]
    }
];
    $scope.rankOrder = 'rank';
    $scope.query = '';




    $scope.matchEveryWord = function() {
        return function( item ) {
            var string = JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase();
            var words = $scope.query.toLowerCase();

            if(words){
                var filterBy = words.split(/\s+/);
                if(!filterBy.length){
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }

            return filterBy.every(function (word){

                var exists = string.indexOf(word);
                if(exists !== -1){
                    return true;
                }
            });

        };
    };
}]);
```

Comment: did you look at ng-hide or ng-show yet?

Comment: Yes id did, no luck so far

Answer (score 0):

In your li element,  add ng-show to show subcategories only if questions are present. Something like:-

```
 <li ng-repeat="subcategory in category.subcategories | filter:matchEveryWord()" ng-show="areQuestionsPresent(subcategory)">
```

Now, in your controller, define a method areQuestionsPresent, that will evaluate whether there are any questions or not:-

```
$scope.areQuestionsPresent = function(category) {
    return category.questions.length > 0;
}
```

I am in a hurry otherwise would have given some more details. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this before, I can't get it working because of the nesting. Could you adjust the fiddle and get it working? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try nesting the two loops together, and only displaying the category title once.
That will change your current setup a bit (you can place your list back, I used a `div` because it was quicker for me), but it works:

```
        <div ng-repeat="subcategory in category.subcategories | filter:matchEveryWord()">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="question in subcategory.questions | filter:matchEveryWord()">

                     <h3 ng-if="$first">{{subcategory.subcategory}}</h3>

                     <h4 class="bullet">{{question.question}}</h4>

                    <div>{{question.answer}}</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lp02huqm/5/

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, this has no different output than my fiddle, and I do want to hide the subcategory if there are no questions in it

Comment: True that. I'm changing my answer.